# Label and button don't go in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

In my iPhone project, I have a mapview. I have one custom button and a label on map view. When user clicks on a pin a callOutAnnotation is called. I have a different class for CallOutAnnotation. A view for callOutAnnotation appears on the map. When CallOutAnnotation view appears on the map, the custom Button and label appear over the CallOutAnnotation view. I have tried a lot more things but they don't go to back of CallOutAnnotation view. need help.

Thanks and regards,
PC

Comment: Could you post some code so I can take a look at the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you've placed a label and a button **over your map**, which is pretty much the problem you're having.

What happens now is that any subviews added to your mapView are automatically below your label and a button. You could try adding them as subviews to your map (I'm not sure if this will work), but probably the best way to go around this is to place the button and the label somewhere less out of the way.

Comment: I actually got the answer.. for mapview, apple follows a hierarchy of layers.. And according to that this issue cannot be solved... anyways, thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

You could always try changing the alpha of the button and the label to 0 when you want them to be hidden then back to 1 when they should reappear.

```
    button1.alpha = 0;
```

You can even animate this if you want to:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    //enter code
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope it helps!